# Delete record from datasheet with vba DatasheetDoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord (error 2046)

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, ms-access-2007

Please help me!

**What I have:**

First, I'm using Access 2007. I have a form that include's a subform. In that subform a have a datasheet from a SQL query which get 3 fields. The first field (Supprimer) his a dummy field to display a hyperlink that will be use has a button:

```
SELECT "Supprimer", permis.abbreviation, permis.description
FROM permis 
INNER JOIN (clients INNER JOIN clients_permis 
  ON clients.ID=clients_permis.id_clients) 
  ON permis.ID=clients_permis.id_permis;
```

**What I want**
I want my "delete" hyperlinks to delete the datasheet selected record has would pressing the "del" key would

**My code for onClick event**

```
Private Sub del_Click()

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
    'SendKeys ("{DELETE}")       
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord

End Sub
```

If I uncommented, the *Sendkeys ("{DELETE}")* the record is deleted, but, on my systeme this also triggers the numlock key. Who knows what it can do on other system.

the *DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord* command provokes a *Run-Time Error: 2046*.

At a previous point the above code worked perfectly.

Comment: Sub question: How bad is it to use the SendKeys() methode?

Comment: I cannot possibly recommend using SendKeys. You might look at this link if you haven't already. http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/archive/index.php/t-60046.html There does seem to be a lack of conclusion about what causes this error your getting when trying to delete a record the way you are. You might try running compact and repair to see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your recordset is updateable?  Why are you using a dummy field to delete rather than a command button? I agree that under no circumstances should you use sendkeys, nor should it be necessary.

Comment: Using a command button will set the focus off the datasheet and i won't be able to use "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord".

Comment: Continuous forms (as opposed to datasheet forms) allow you to include buttons although you cannot allow your users to easily move columns and apply sorting with continuous forms.

Comment: Another way you can do this is create a Public DeleteRecord function/sub on the subform and call it from the Main Form. The fact that the focus moves to the main form will not affect the subform's ability to delete the current record.

Comment: Thanks you HK1. Your two last suggestion are great. I will probably use the public delete record function though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by HK1, here's what can be done (although it's workaround):

Use a continuous form instead of the datasheet.

Comment: Continuous form is a form (obviously), thus it allow's you to add a button like in any other form. With datasheet buttons dont work as well because cliking anything outside the datasheet (for example the wanted button) will put the datasheet out of focus. Putting the datasheet out of focus will 'unselect' the selected record.

Plus continuous form, in my case, gives me more options. Even the option to design it so it look like a datasheet.

Comment: It is NOT true that clicking outside a datasheet form unselects the current record in the datasheet. That assertion is JUST COMPLETELY WRONG.